# Insert null value in database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a database in MySQL Workbench with fields like (name, lastname, age, address, etc..) and a windows desktop application (a form) in visual studio with c# where you can insert, search and update.
When I insert data from the form and I leave some fields empty, they are saved in the database as blank and I want them to be saved as null.
Is there a way to make that happen?

Here is and insert button code:

```
conn = openconnection.GetConn();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name (name,lastname,address, etc...) VALUES (' " + name_textbox.Text + " ',' " + lastname_textbox.Text + " ' etc... );", conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Thanks a lot, it works fine but I have a problem with words with spaces, like: (father name , mother name , etc). When I insert a value at name it is fine but when I insert a value at father name or mother name it is null. I think it is because of space between words.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name (name,`father name`,`mother name`, etc... VALUES (@name,@`father name`,@`mother name`,etc...);", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name_textbox.Text.NullString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@`father name`", father_name_textbox.Text.NullString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@`mother name`", mother_name_textbox.Text.NullString());

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to simply do the interpretation on your own:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(name_textbox.Text) ? null : string.Format("'{0}'", name_textbox.Text);
```

However, I want to give you another option:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = openconnection.GetConn())
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name (name,lastname,address) VALUES (@name,@lastname,@address);", conn);
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name_textbox.Text.NullString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname_textbox.Text.NullString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address_textbox.Text.NullString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string NullString(this string s)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution you'll be properly disposing the connection and command objects, but you'll also be able to streamline the string to `null` process **and** leverage prepared queries to make the process simpler **and** safer because it's not open to SQL Injection.

**NOTE:** the static class that you see should be placed in its own `.cs` file.

Comment: Does `SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue(name, value)` have an overload that only accepts a single argument?

Comment: @canon, yes you're right, just a typo. Thanks for catching that, I've edited the answer!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thanks, I try your code but in: `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? DBNull.Value : (object)s;` line i have an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) I try `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? DBNull.Value : (object)s.ToString();` but didnt work. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thanks Michael works fine except the words with space between, look my edit. Have you any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris you won't be able to have spaces in the parameter names so you'll have to use the underscore. However, as long as you're using the back tick you'll be able to reference your column names (and it looks to me you already are). Further, don't use back ticks around the parameter names.

Comment: In the 'interpretaion on your own' line, the null should be in double quotes (c# string).  The other thing to note seems to be that you don't need DBNull.value for strings in parameters.  Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this nifty Function to test/insert `DBNull.Value`.

```
    public static object ToDBNull(object value)
    {
        if (null != value)
            return value;
        return DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Useful in other places but for your case:

```
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name (name,lastname,address, etc...)" +
    "VALUES (' " + ToDBNull(name_textbox.Text) + " ',' " + ToDBNull(lastname_textbox.Text) + " ' etc... );", conn)
```

Also, you should consider your vulnerability to SQL injection attacks and consider Parameterized SQL command.

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it does...  Unless mysql has some way to interpret null's within quotes.  And it only works with strings, and not nullable values -- and it seems that strings don't need the DBNull.value construct.

Answer (score -1):

Though the columns appear as blanks in the database they are actually null. You can verify this by reading those fields in C# and comparing it with System.DBNull.

Comment: Actually, if the empty string value of the text box were sent to the database it would literally store an empty string, which is very different than `null`.